# React Native - Unable to resolve module `node_modules/react/index.js/jsx-runtime`

Tags: react-native

I'm in the process of upgrading react native and I've been stuck on the following error for the past few days:

```
 BUNDLE  ./index.ts 

error: Error: Unable to resolve module 
monorepo/app/node_modules/react/index.js/jsx-runtime from monorepo/mobileChat/src/screens/index.tsx: 

None of these files exist:
  * node_modules/react/index.js/jsx-runtime(.native|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
  * node_modules/react/index.js/jsx-runtime/index(.native|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
> 1 | import React from 'react'
  2 | import { Navigation } from 'react-native-navigation'
  3 | import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
  4 | import getStore from 'shared/store'
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (/Users/tbrownio/repos/bloom/bloomtext-frontend/mobileChat/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:152:15)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/Users/tbrownio/repos/bloom/bloomtext-frontend/mobileChat/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:264:43)
    at Object.resolve (/Users/tbrownio/repos/bloom/bloomtext-frontend/mobileChat/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:170:21)
    at resolveDependencies (/Users/tbrownio/repos/bloom/bloomtext-frontend/mobileChat/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/graphOperations.js:466:33)
    at processModule (/Users/tbrownio/repos/bloom/bloomtext-frontend/mobileChat/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/graphOperations.js:232:31)
    at async addDependency (/Users/tbrownio/repos/bloom/bloomtext-frontend/mobileChat/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/graphOperations.js:361:18)
    at async Promise.all (index 9)
    at async processModule (/Users/tbrownio/repos/bloom/bloomtext-frontend/mobileChat/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/graphOperations.js:279:3)
    at async addDependency (/Users/tbrownio/repos/bloom/bloomtext-frontend/mobileChat/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/graphOperations.js:361:18)
    at async Promise.all (index 3)
```

I'm trying to understand why the path is resolving to `...node_modules/react/index.js/jsx-runtime.` I'm not what's causing the path to be created like this. the correct path should be `...node_modules/react/jsx-runtime.`

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "mobileChat",
  "workspaces": {
    "nohoist": [
      "jetifier",
      "react-native",
      "react-native/**",
      "@react-native-community/**",
      "react-native-navigation",
      "react-native-onesignal",
      "react-native-version-number",
      "react-native-image-crop-picker",
      "react-native-video",
      "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view",
      "@sentry/**",
      "@amplitude/react-native",
      "react",
      "@testing-library/react-native",
      "@types/react-native"
    ]
  },
  "version": "3.22.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "run-ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "run-android": "react-native run-android",
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "ts": "tsc --noEmit --jsx react-native --project tsconfig.json",
    "ts:watch": "yarn ts --watch",
    "test": "yarn jest",
    "test:watch": "yarn jest --watch",
    "version": "react-native-version --never-increment-build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@amplitude/react-native": "2.16.1",
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "7.13.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.12.5",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.15.17",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^3.5.2",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "4.7.0",
    "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.10.0",
    "@react-native-community/toolbar-android": "^0.2.1",
    "@react-native-cookies/cookies": "6.0.11",
    "@sentry/react-native": "4.6.1",
    "@stream-io/flat-list-mvcp": "^0.10.1",
    "linkify-it": "3.0.3",
    "mdurl": "^1.0.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.6",
    "react-native-audio": "https://github.com/bloomapi/react-native-audio",
    "react-native-bidirectional-infinite-scroll": "^0.3.3",
    "react-native-deep-linking": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-get-random-values": "^1.8.0",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "0.38.0",
    "react-native-iphone-x-helper": "1.3.1",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "0.9.5",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "2.5.6",
    "react-native-navigation": "7.27.1",
    "react-native-onesignal": "4.3.3",
    "react-native-swipe-list-view": "^3.2.9",
    "react-native-version-number": "0.3.6",
    "react-native-video": "^6.0.0-alpha.3",
    "react-redux": "7.2.2",
    "redux": "4.0.5",
    "redux-logger": "3.0.6",
    "redux-persist": "4.10.2",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "0.12.0",
    "text-encoding-polyfill": "^0.6.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.16.11",
    "@testing-library/jest-native": "^4.0.1",
    "@testing-library/react-hooks": "^7.0.1",
    "@testing-library/react-native": "^8.0.0",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.23",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.21",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.70.6",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "26.6.3",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "4.1.0",
    "get-yarn-workspaces": "^1.0.2",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.72.3",
    "react-native-version": "^4.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.1.0",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
    "typescript": "^4.8.3"
  }
}
```

Here's my metro.config.js

```
/**
 * Metro configuration for React Native
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 */
const path = require('path')
const getWorkspaces = require('get-yarn-workspaces')

const extraNodeModules = {
  'mobile': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
  'components': 'mobile/components',
  'screens': 'mobile/screens',
}

const workspaces = getWorkspaces(__dirname)
const watchFolders = [
  path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'node_modules'),
  ...workspaces.filter(dir => dir !== __dirname),
]

module.exports = {
  transformer: {
    getTransformOptions: async () => ({
      transform: {
        experimentalImportSupport: false,
        inlineRequires: false,
      },
    }),
  },
  resolver: {
    extraNodeModules,
  },
  watchFolders,
}
```

Here's my babel.config.js

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  "presets": ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "module-resolver",
      {
        "extensions": [".ios.js", ".android.js", ".js", ".json"],
        "alias": {
          "react": require.resolve('react', { paths: [path.join(__dirname, './')] }),
          '^react-native$': require.resolve('react-native', { paths: [path.join(__dirname, './')] }),
          '^react-native/(.+)': ([, name]) => require.resolve(`react-native/${name}`, { paths: [path.join(__dirname, './')] }),
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
}
```

Been really stuck on this. Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into the same issue when upgrading from expo SDK 45 to 46.

It turns out that completely removing the `module-resolver` from my `babel.config.js` file resolved the issue.
Even if you don't use expo, I still suggest you to investigate this way